# How cvxpy determine the type of model

Tags: optimization, cvxpy

I built a model with **only integer variables** （Boolean, 0-1 variable）.The problem is identified as LO (liner optimize) when i don't choose the solver.But when i choose the solver like GLPK/SCS, it will report an error “cvxpy.error.SolverError: Problem is mixed-integer, but candidate QP/Conic solvers ([]) are not MIP-capable.”

Comment: If the model has integer variables CVXPY must solve a MIP capable solver. Or you can name such solver explicitly. Even if the problem contains integer variables it can still be called as LO when everything is linear (as opposed to if it had some nonlinearities)

Comment: yes,  that's what i don't understand.  Why CVXPY must solve a MIP capable solver if the model has integer variables. i checked the condition ：is_mixed_integer-> any(v.attributes['boolean'] or v.attributes["integer'])

Comment: A non-MIP capable solver cannot solve a MIP. Maybe you should post a small reproducible example to give a better idea of the issue.